# How to mock class with param, return this class. As when(new A(any(B.class))).thenReturn(any(A.class));

Tags: mocking

I need mock as `when(new A(any(B.class))).thenReturn(any(A.class));`
because my code have function:
`B b = new B; A a = new A(b); C c = a.processing();`
but return error:
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException:
Misplaced or misused argument matcher detected here:
-> at .......
You cannot use argument matchers outside of verification or stubbing.
Examples of correct usage of argument matchers:
`when(mock.get(anyInt())).thenReturn(null); doThrow(new RuntimeException()).when(mock).someVoidMethod(anyObject()); verify(mock).someMethod(contains("foo"))`

This message may appear after an NullPointerException if the last matcher is returning an object
like any() but the stubbed method signature expect a primitive argument, in this case,
use primitive alternatives.
`when(mock.get(any()));` // bad use, will raise NPE
 `when(mock.get(anyInt()));` // correct usage use

Also, this error might show up because you use argument matchers with methods that cannot be mocked.
Following methods *cannot* be `stubbed/verified: final/private/equals()/hashCode().`
Mocking methods declared on non-public parent classes is not supported.

What should I do?
Thanks all